# Trouble displaying an error when custom value is entered in a textbox

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, master-pages

I am working in Visual Studio 2012 and I am having trouble trying to display a simple error message via a label for a textbox I have created for the duration in Years. For example, if a user enters in 'dfasdfsa' in the txtYears textbox the error "Years must be a numeric Value" will display. To make it more clear I will provide what the ID's stand for.

```
txtPrincliple = Priciple amount for a loan
txtYears = duration of the loan in years
lblResult = Result to the button click and the solution 
rblYears = radiobuttonList for duration in years
MonthlyPayment() = is a created method that returns the Monthly payment from provide input

  protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
    bool error = false;
    //Display Error if non numeric is entered
    if (!double.TryParse(txtPrinciple.Text, out principle))
    {
        error = true;
        lblResult.Text = "The principle must be a numeric value!";
    }

    //Get the values
    if (rblYears.SelectedIndex == 0)
        years = 15;
    else if (rblYears.SelectedIndex == 1)
        years = 30;
    else
        double.TryParse(txtYears.Text, out years);
    //Display Error if custom duration is entered
    if (!double.TryParse(txtYears.Text, out years))
    {
        error = true;
        lblResult.Text = "The years must be a numeric value!";
    }
    //Get interest rate value
    double.TryParse(ddlInterestRate.SelectedValue, out interest);
    //Output the Monthly Payment if no errors
    if (!error)
    {
        lblResult.Text = string.Format("Your total monthly payment is {0}{1:0.00}",   "$", MonthlyPayment());
    }
 }
```

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: I am trying to display a simple error message for the textYears with the lblResult. I cannot seem to get the error message to work when a user selects the 15 Years or 30 Years from the rblYears it says "The years must be a numeric value!" I want it to do the calculation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I see, the problem seems to come from the fact that you do the error validation even if the user chose something from the RBL. I'm not totally sure I understood the question however, it's not very clear.

It should work if you change it to

```
//Get the values
    if (rblYears.SelectedIndex == 0)
        years = 15;
    else if (rblYears.SelectedIndex == 1)
        years = 30;
    else
    {
        //Display Error if custom duration is entered
        if (!double.TryParse(txtYears.Text, out years))
        {
            error = true;
            lblResult.Text = "The years must be a numeric value!";
        }
    }
```

I also removed the redundant first TryParse (since you do it while validating)